# How to get the current slide position in Swipe 2? getPos not working

Tags: javascript

Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577646/swipe-js-getpos-and-getnumslides-help-needed

Does not seem to work. Since I'm not an expert at Javascript I can't solve this. 
Any help on how to make the function work will be appreciated.

Thanks!